# product for two conditional probability

Tags: probability

I'm trying to figure our whether the following two equations are correct:

1. $$
   P(A|C)=P(A|B)*P(B|C)
   $$
2. $$
   P_{X|Z}(x|z)=\sum_{y}P_{X|Y}(x|y)*P_{Y|Z}(y|z)
   $$
   Any hint or counter example are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The Law of Total Probability is: 
   $$\mathsf P(A\mid C) ~=~ \mathsf P(A\mid B, C)~\mathsf P(B\mid C)+\mathsf P(A\mid \neg B, C)~\mathsf P(\neg B\mid C)$$
2. And likewise : $$p_{X\mid Z}(x\mid z) ~=~\sum\limits_{y\in \textsf{support}(Y)}p_{X\mid Y,Z}(x\mid y,z)~p_{Y\mid Z}(y\mid z)$$

Comment: Great. You saved me from thinking all night!